# Query never end on a particular value / row

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a huge table with a million of row.

With index on a column say `TableA.uid`, the query `select * from TableA where uid = 123` usually returns in a second.

I've deleted the record by

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE uid = 123

-- with a few other tables 
-- ...

COMMIT
```

Now when query `select * from TableA where uid = 123` it never ends.

But `select * from TableA where uid = [other value]` can return a row.

Tried `sp_who2` but couldn't find any lock.

What's the possible cause, and how to fix?

Comment: What is the wait type that is accumulating while the query runs long?

Comment: Are you sure that commit was executed?

Comment: Sounds like blocking to me...

Comment: Can you please tell us table size, number of columns and datatypes apart from int, char, varchar, nvarchar you have used?

Comment: As @TiborKaraszi already suggested it's a blocking. Look like a stored proc was previously terminated without a proper commit. What confusing is it's not detected by any job monitor query. Restarting server has resolved the issue. Thanks folks